# Return data in Message instead of Grid

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, raiserror

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Employee where code = 'testcode1')
INSERT INTO 
    Employee(code, fname, lname)
VALUES
('testcode1', 'testfn', testln')
ELSE
    RAISERROR (SELECT * FROM Employee where code = 'testcode1', 11, 1)
```

How I could return the result if the data is already exist in Message not in Grid?

Sample Output

```
  Code         fname     lname
 ------------- --------  -----------
  tescode1      testfn   testln
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a message variable and raise that. For example:

```
DECLARE @Message varchar(200)

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Employee where code = 'testcode1')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
    Employee(code, fname, lname)
    VALUES
    ('testcode1', 'testfn', 'testln')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @Message = FNAME + ' ' + LNAME FROM Employee where code = 'testcode1'
    RAISERROR (@Message, 11, 1)
END
```